# Why do I get different returns from preg_replace() function?

Tags: php, regex

I am having a problem with PHP's `preg_replace()` function.

```
$string="[y-z]y-z_y[y_z]yav[v_v]";  // i want it to become : [y-z]yellow-zend_yellow[y_z]yav[v_v]

$find = array('/y(?=(?:.(?!\]))*\[)/Um', '/a(?=(?:.(?!\]))*\[)/Um', '/z(?=(?:.(?!\]))*\[)/Um', '/v(?=(?:.(?!\]))*\[)/Um');

$replace = array('yellow', 'avocado', 'zend', 'vodka');

echo preg_replace($find, $replace, $string)."<br><br>"; // display [y-zend]yellow-zend_yellow[y_zend]yellowavodkaocadovodka[v_v]

echo preg_replace('/y(?=(?:.(?!\]))*\[)/Um', 'yellow', $string)."<br><br>"; // display [y-z]yellow-z_yellow[y_z]yellowav[v_v]

echo preg_replace('/z(?=(?:.(?!\]))*\[)/Um', 'zend', $string)."<br><br>"; // display [y-zend]y-zend_y[y_zend]yav[v_v] --Why displaying zend inside[]?
```

Also, I want to know if there is a way to do this in simple PHP with an additional condition: if there is any "yav" string between "][", I want to ignore it.

```
**[y-z]y-z_y[y_z]yav[v_v] ==> [y-z]yellow-zend_yellow[y_z]yav[v_v]**
```

OR

**`$var=[y-z]y-z[y_z]yav[v_v]; ==> $var=[y-z]yellow-zend[y_z]yav[v_v];`**

Comment: How do you tell ` ]y- ` from ` ]ya `   Here I just changed your life lol, click me > https://regex101.com/

Comment: do string_replace('y-z_y', 'yellow-zend_yellow', '[y-z]y-z_y[y_z]yav[v_v]');

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix No, not Working If the var is : [y-z]y-z[y_z]yav[v_v] ==> [y-z] yellow-zend[y_z]yav[v_v] i need some thing to work with all cases and without using to much memory and replace every word with a specific string

Comment: what are all cases, you could add them for example and include the ][ in the replacements.  Such as string_replace(array(']y-z_y[',']y-z[') , array(']yellow-zend_yellow[', ']yellow-zend['), '[y-z]y-z_y[y_z]yav[v_v]'); etc..

Answer (score 2):

The last z] matches becase you told it to use a positive look ahead to match a negative look ahead,  it's basically an oxymoron.

Your telling it to match the z if the lookahead matches, while not matching what you don't want, so it matches what you don't want and says ok it matches.  It sort of makes sense in my head anyway.

https://regex101.com/r/nX5dQ6/1

Can you quantify your rules to match multiple character sequences, surely its much easier to replace `y-z_y` with `yellow-zend_yellow` But with no context it's impossible to say if this could be possible.

```
/z(?=(?:.(?!\]))*\[)/Um
    z matches the character z literally (case sensitive)
    (?=(?:.(?!\]))*\[) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
        (?:.(?!\]))* Non-capturing group
            Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
            . matches any character (except newline)
            (?!\]) Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below
                \] matches the character ] literally
        \[ matches the character [ literally
    U modifier: Ungreedy. The match becomes lazy by default. Now a ? following a quantifier makes it greedy
    m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
```

**Personally** I would probably make a **tokenizer** for it, the idea would be to use preg_match_all instead, like this

```
 $matches = null;
 $returnValue = preg_match_all('/(?P<T_OPEN>\[)|(?P<T_CLOSE>\])|(?P<T_Y>y)|(?P<T_X>x)|(?P<T_Z>z)|(?P<T_SEPH>\-)|(?P<T_SEPU>\_)/', '[y-z]y-z_y[y_z]yav[v_v]', $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Return

```
 array (
    0 => 
         array (
               0 => '[',
               1 => 'y',
               2 => '-',
               3 => 'z',
               4 => ']',
             ...
        ),
   'T_OPEN' => 
        array (
            0 => '[',
            1 => '',
            2 => '',
            3 => '',
            4 => '',
   ..
```

And with some post processing this can be simplified down to a list of tokens

```
 array('T_OPEN', 'T_Y', 'T_SEPH', 'T_Z', 'T_CLOSE', ...);
```

Which are the named capture groups, then it's pretty trivial to write some logic to determine if you are in a [ ] group or not, or if the T_Y, T_X, T_Z was preceded by another T_Y, T_X, T_Z token as you go through the list, that is the most robust way to do it.

To process it down to just the tokens use a for loop on the [0][0] match and see if the others have a value like this ( not tested, but that's the basis of it )

```
 $total = count($matches[0][0]);
    // remove numbered keys this is just an array of all the string keys, our tokens
 $tokens = array_filter( function( $item ){
       return preg_match('/^[^0-9]/', $item );
 }, array_keys( $matches ) );
 $tokens[] = 'T_UNKNOWN'; //add a default token for validation

 $tokenstream = array();
 for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++){
     //loop through the matches  for the index,
         foreach($tokens as $token ){
           //loop through the tokens and check $matches[$token][$i] for length
             if( strlen($matches[$token][$i]) > 0 ){
                  break; //break out of the foreach when we find our token which is now in $token - if we don't find it it's the last token T_UNKNOWN
             }
          }
         $tokenstream[] = $token;
}
```

Then you build your string from scratch using the tokens,

```
 $out = '';
 $literal = false;

  foreach( $tokenstream as $offset => $token ){
        switch( $token ){
            case 'T_OPEN':
                  $out .= '[';
                  $literal = true;  //start brackets
            break;
            case 'T_CLOSE':
                  $out .= ']';
                  $literal = false; //end brackets
            break;
            case 'T_SEPH':
                  $out .= '-';
            break;
            case 'T_Y':
                   if( $literal ){  //if inside brackets literal y 
                      $out .= 'y';
                   }else{  // else use the word yellow
                      $out .= 'yellow';
                   }
            break;
            case 'T_UNKNOWN':
                   //validate
                   throw new Exception( "Error unknown token at offset: $offset");

         }
   }
```

You'd still need to figure out the T_Z followed by a T_A, etc. etc. but that would be a sure fire way to do it, and avoids all that mess above.  Plus it's a pretty gnarly way of thinking about a problem like this.

Comment: No sir, and what if i have : $var=[y-z]y-z[y_z]yav[v_v]; ==> $var=[y-z] yellow-zend[y_z]yav[v_v];. and how can i ingore words in string yav

Comment: How should I know, it's your problem, what are some sample inputs, one input is not enough to figure that out.  There are many ways to do this you could preg_split using the [y-z] group, etc.

Comment: thanks, this is very close to my old solution with array, loop and switch but it's take memory with large variables. for this reason I thought that if i use a simple way with replace function i decrease some memory usage but it seem not possible. by the way i need this to do some sort of html enc0ding i load larges html sources to the memory to work with. to display encoding <p>p</p> for exemple the result : <%70>&#%78%37%30;</%70> i need to replace every word alone and words between > < with different values. thanks for your comments i greatly appreciate ^^'

Comment: This should be fine memory wise, if fact I am using this method ( similar ) to parse template pages, so whole files can be parsed this way.  See my github page, in the case of a whole page, make a token that is (?P<T_CONTENT>.) or  such because tokens will be matched in the order of the pattern you use.  Also you can use a more efficient way, as I do in my templates by useing the offset capture flag. https://github.com/ArtisiticPhoenix/Jet/blob/master/Jet/lib/Jet/Lexer.php

Comment: The PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE flag will return the index in the input string where the match starts, then with the length of the match you can use simple substr and such to find exactly where your match is an take bigger chunks of text essentially which reduces the array needed to tokenism.  In fact the php interpreter uses a tokenizer to parse the php language,